# How to do long-term HTTP delivery retrying?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

Scenario:

1. Many messages in JMS queue
2. MDB delivers them to remote HTTP server
3. Remote server can be down
4. Retry mechanism is needed that will not clog up the entire server.
5. Redelivery runs for few days, every 1 hour.

My idea is to have MDB attempt redelivery at once, when the new message arrives in the JMS queue, but to limit this to, say, 5 times every 1 minute. Then the message is removed from JMS queue and put in database. Another (@Scheduled) EJB will then take the unsent messages from DB every 1 hour, and send them in its own thread.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, but it depends on JMS provider that you use. Unfortunately, at the moment there is no support for delayed messages in JMS API, which is definitely the most elegant solution of your problem. However, if you are using some of the following JMS provider: Oracle AQ, JBoss, OpenJMS, ActiveMQ; they have built-in support for delayed messages through call:

```
msg.setLongProperty("SOME-PROVIDER-SPECIFIC-PARAMETER, delay);
```

Reference:

- [Sending delayed JMS Messages](http://java.dzone.com/articles/sending-delayed-jms-messages)